# 1D random walk python

Tags: python

I am trying to use a for loop to simulate 5 random walks and plot them all on the same graph.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=-1
b=1
def random_walk5(n):

    x=[]
    y=[]
    x.append(0)
    y.append(0)
    for j in (1,2,3,4,5):
        for i in range(n):
            r = a+(b-a)*np.random.rand()
            step = y[i]+(5/3)*r
            xstep =x[i]+1
            y.append(step)
            x.append(xstep)
            return x, y

x, y = random_walk5(200)

plt.title("Random walk")
plt.xlabel("Number of steps")
plt.ylabel("")
plt.plot(x, y, '.-')
```

This is my attempt. I previously did a simulation for just one random walk and that worked.

Here is my code for the just one simulation, it worked perfectly I just can't seem to modify it to it produces all the five random walks and plots them, any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
def random_walk(n):

    x=[]
    y=[]
    x.append(0)
    y.append(0)
    for i in range(n):
        r = a+(b-a)*np.random.rand()
        step = y[i]+(5/3)*r
        xstep =x[i]+1
        y.append(step)
        x.append(xstep)
    return x, y

x, y = random_walk(200)

plt.title("Random walk")
plt.xlabel("Number of steps")
plt.ylabel("")
plt.plot(x, y, '.-')
```

Comment: Read your code and study what it does (first step before posting a question) - a hint: the second attempt creates one curve with around 1000 points, the first attempt created a curve with 200 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is an issue with `random_walk5` method, as the `return` statement is inside the for body. This will break the loops after the first iteration.

However, it's possible to use the `random_walk` method in a for loop (as big as the number of random walk you want):

```py
plt.title("Random walk")
plt.xlabel("Number of steps")
plt.ylabel("")
for _ in range(5):
    plt.plot(*random_walk(200), ".-")
plt.show()
```